# "Diteggiare" riferito alla tastiera di un cellulare: si tratta di un uso insolito?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Nel romanzo *Prendiluna*, di Stefano Benni, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> – Michele, – disse Dolcino – so come rintracciare Prendiluna. Abbiamo il suo numero di cellulare. 
>         – Che fessi, potevamo pensarci prima – disse Michele. 
>         – Proprio così... Sei capace di usarlo? 
>         – Certo. Ne ho rubati tanti. 
>         **Diteggiò**. Sentirono una suoneria proprio alle loro spalle, era *A dream is a wish your heart makes* di David-Hoffman-Livingston. Ovverossia *I sogni son desideri* dal film *Cenerentola*.

Ho cercato il verbo "diteggiare" in parecchi dizionari, ma ho trovato soltanto accezioni che fanno riferimento alla musica.

Sul libro [*La scrittura cerca l'assassino. (È gradito l'alibi di sera)*](https://books.google.es/books?id=Saa_n_2km2AC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=diteggiare&source=bl&ots=hlEbpOOupY&sig=ACfU3U0hVxwpuWDhPzeUq8j-wvert6ZQYw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO5fCG0-rpAhVbBGMBHfg5Cv4Q6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=diteggiare&f=false), di Carlo Villa, però, ne ho trovato un altro esempio riferito a un cellulare (anche qui il grassetto è mio):

> Eppure nel formare il numero è inquieta; manipola il cellulare, ma è da quando col marito s'è installata nel residence per essere più libera e meno osservata nei suoi movimenti, che ci prova; fin dalle dieci di mattina, ma il numero risulta sempre isolato. Evidentemente ha spento
>   l'apparecchio. Ora approfitta del sensibile ritardo del marito, e riprova di nuovo, ma il numero risulta ogni volta inerte. Continua a **diteggiare** la tastiera con stizza, e intanto si domanda come mai tutta questa messa in scena, e che senso ha averla fatta venire fin quassù, dal momento che poi lui non ci viene mai.

Ricercando "diteggiare" su Google Libri si trovano soprattutto esempi nell'ambito della musica: questo mi sembra naturale, poiché è l'uso che appare nei dizionari.

La mia domanda sarebbe: l'uso del verbo "diteggiare" riferito alla tastiera di un cellulare è qualcosa di  insolito? O 
è diventato più o meno comune?

Comment: È un verbo abbastanza insolito. Riferito alla tastiera di in cellulare o un computer no l’ho mai sentito o visto usare. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22diteggiare%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_it

Comment: Mi pare una buona estensione del significato musicale. La diteggiatura è sia l'indicazione di come usare le dita, sia l'uso stesso delle dita sullo strumento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con diteggiare si intende "digitare caratteri sulla tastiera". L'uso è alquanto infrequente e nel linguaggio colloquiale non viene adoperato.

Nella musica la "diteggiatura" corrisponde al modo in cui disponi le mani per suonare lo strumento (piano, chitarra...).